# Proof verification that if $y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_n$ converges then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Let $\{x_n\}, n\in\Bbb N$ denote a sequence such that the sequence:
>   $$
> \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n x_n \right\}
> $$
>   converges. Prove that:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0
> $$

Please note that it is $x_n$ under the sum sign, which i believe is a typo, isn't it? I have replaced it with $x_k$ below.

Let:
$$
y_n = \left\{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k \right\}
$$

We know that $y_n$ converges, hence is satisfies the Cauchy criteria:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N\in\Bbb N: \forall n,m > N \implies |y_n - y_m| < \epsilon
$$

Consider $|y_n - y_m|$ for $m>n$:
$$
\begin{align}
|y_n - y_m| 
&= |y_m - y_n| \\ 
&= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m x_k\right| \\
&\ge \sum_{k=n+1}^m |x_k| \\ 
&= |x_{n+1}| + |x_{n+2}| + \cdots + |x_m| \\
&\ge |x_{n+1}|
\end{align}
$$

So we have:
$$
|x_{n+1}| \le |y_n - y_m| < \epsilon
$$

Which means:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N\in\Bbb N: \forall n> N \implies |x_{n+1}| < \epsilon
$$

But that is the definition of a limit, thus:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0
$$

Is my proof valid? Also is it really a typo in the book or am I missing something?

Comment: A bit easier: $x_n = y_{n+1} - y_n$, and since the series $(y_n)_n$ converges, the limit is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (y_{n+1} - y_n) = 0$.

Comment: @ComplexFlo I think you mean $x_{n+1}$ but of course the same argument applies with the Shift Rule.

Comment: @AlephNull you're completely right, it should be $x_{n+1}$ actually! But the argument stays valid anyway. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is not valid since your triangle inequality is reversed in sign.

That is $$\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^mx_k \right| \le\sum_{k=n+1}^m|x_k| $$

You might like to use Cauchy condition on $y_n$ and show that

$$|y_n - y_{n-1}|=|x_n|$$

can be arbitrarily close to $0$.